# JQuery looping through each table row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following table structure

```
<table class="ms-listviewtable>
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb2-icon"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2">test1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb2-icon"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2">test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb2-icon"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2"/>
<td class="ms-vb2">test3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to loop through each row then loop through each td and check if a td in a row contains the text 'test1' if so I need hide the td with class "ms-vb2-icon" within the same row.

Can someone please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("tr:has(td:contains('test1')) td.ms-vb2-icon").hide();
```

[You can test the code against your markup here](http://jsfiddle.net/wYaM8/)

This uses [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to see if a `<td>` contains that text, wrapped in [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to see if the the `<tr>` has an element matching that, the next we're finding the `td.ms-vb2-icon` cell in the matched rows and hiding them.

Comment: Many thanks for your explaination as well. I can see it working in the fiddle.

Just not sure why its hiding the td on all rows in my webpart, unless the html table structure I see in IE developer toolbar isn't the same as the generated html code....

Comment: @nav - I had to fix your markup a bit in fiddle, for example `<td>` can't be self-closing and the `<table>` element's `class` needs a closing quote.   Make sure your actual markup is valid by checking it here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks Nick i have pasted the actual markup into the fiddle  edit http://jsfiddle.net/QUvYW/

Comment: sorry to be a pain, but can you spot why it doesnt work as expected in my edited fiddle..?

Comment: @nav - You still have invalid markup, all sorts of attributes...but it is still working, at least here in Chrome and IE, comment out the jQuery like this to see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/QUvYW/1/

Comment: i tried to do something a little different - to look for the td with the text test1 and disable the link on the same row but it doesnt seem to work...i should probably repost this as a seperate question, thanks.
http://jsfiddle.net/QUvYW/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td:contains('test1')").addClass("ms-vb2-icon");
```

?

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/